# Post Exchange Setup Issues - Can't connect

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, outlook-2003, exchange-2016

I have never setup an Exchange server before.

I am trying to setup an Exchange 2016 server.

I got the pre-reqs setup;
.NET 4.5.2
Microsoft Unified Communications Managed API 4.0 Core Runtime 64-bit.exe

I did the setup, checked off MailBox role and told it to install all the pre-reqs that it could do on it's own.

The only warnings I got were about Exchange 2010 roles no longer being able to install.

Now I'm at post setup. I was able to log in to the webpage portal and I can configure anything in there since I'm the administrator.

--- The Problem ---

So, what now?

This is a test network;

```
192.168.1.1 - Linksys Router
192.168.1.2 - Server 2012r2 Active Directory Domain Controller, DNS, DHCP
192.168.1.3 - Server 2012r2 with Exchange 2016
129.168.1.100 - Client PC (Win 10)

ADDC Settings:
Domain is named ad.testbed.com
NetBios is named testbed
Server is named Core

All firewalls disabled
```

I'm trying to get Thunderbird to access the Exchange server, with no success. I've tried doing a manual configuration.

I added a user (Kayot) to both the ADDC and setup an email account through the portal.

Settings I've tried:

```
imap.ad.testbed.com/192.168.1.3 Auto/993 Autodetect/SSL/TLS Autodetect/Normal password
smtp.ad.testbed.com/192.168.1.3 Auto/465 Autodetect/SSL/TLS Autodetect/Normal password
```

I also tried using Outlook 2003 with Exchange as the mail server.

I created a public folder mailbox to fix an issue where I couldn't link the Exchange to my Outlook program. Issue: "Your Administrator has blocked this version of Outlook"

I keep loosing connection to the server. When I click on the mailbox it says the folder can't be accessed.

I am completely lost. I feel that if I could get Thunderbird to link to the Exchange server then I would be one step closer to figuring out this mess.

I can get hmailserver (I swap OS Harddisks) to connect with the following settings:

```
192.168.1.3 Auto Autodetect Autodetect
192.168.1.3 Auto Autodetect Autodetect
```

So I'm stumped. Tutorials for Exchange do the setup only, or are for things that come with a more complex setup. This is a single system connected to an Active Directory system and being accessed by a single client machine. Nothing special. I want to access it internally first to make sure it works. I feel I am missing some simple step.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to connect to Exchange with Thunderbird instead of Outlook? Wait, why Outlook **2003**? If you have a CAL for Exchange, then you have a license for Outlook 2016. Can you connect with OWA?

Comment: The client that I'm going to be building this for is upgrading their network. They're going from a NT 6.0 DC, XP Clients with Office 97, and a 2008r2 SQL Server to a Visualized Windows 2016 Server, and Windows 10 Enterprise with Office 2016. They want to migrate from a Hosted email/website to internal. I've already migrated/programmed/shifted/kicked everything else without issue. Exchange is just giving me trouble. I use hmailserver and Thunderbird at home so I've never touched Exchange before now. I'll try the Outlook 2016 and see if that works.

Comment: Since the client is going to Windows 10 with Office 2016, your test environment should be based on using those and making sure they work, otherwise you're not really testing the right stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Office/Outlook 2003 support only "MAPI over RPC" while Microsoft Exchange 2016 only supports "MAPI over http". According to the Microsoft documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996719(v=exchg.160).aspx) MS Outlook 2010 (with KB KB2965295) is the oldest version you can use with Microsoft Exchange 2016. So this should explain why you see the "Your Administrator has blocked this version of Outlook" error message and using a newer Outlook client should solve your issue.

P.S.
Installing an Microsoft Exchange 2016 server isn´t that complicated in a small setup, there are a wide range of possible howtos out there which you can find via google. [Here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/206-migrate-from-exchange-2010-to-exchange-2016.html) is a very detailed one to give you an example, you only need to skip the migration steps.